# how to change customize change time_field output step:30min in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ruby, ajax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjeJn.png)
I want to time step:30min interval dropdown.

Comment: May be you can use time_select with minute_step see the following link

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_select

Answer (score -1):

May be you can use time_select with minute_step, see the following link

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_select